# How to know the startup point of an application

Tags: c, linker, embedded, startup

I am using Atmel studio 7.0.

I come to this function when trying to undrestand the code of freeRTOS.

```
/*
* Low-level initialization routine called during startup, before the main
* function.
* This version comes in replacement to the default one provided by the Newlib
 * add-ons library.
 * Newlib add-ons' _init_startup only calls init_exceptions, but Newlib add-ons'
 * exception vectors are not compatible with the SCALL management in the current
 * FreeRTOS port. More low-level initializations are besides added here.
 */
 int _init_startup(void);
 int _init_startup(void)
 {
   /* Import the Exception Vector Base Address. */
   extern void _evba;

    #if configHEAP_INIT
     extern void __heap_start__;
     extern void __heap_end__;
     portBASE_TYPE *pxMem;
   #endif
   ...
```

As you may see in the comment this function is called before the main, however i didn't undrestand who calls this function.

After some research i said that this function can be called in the linker script, however it wasn't the case, the linker script looks like :

```
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-avr32", "elf32-avr32",
      "elf32-avr32")
OUTPUT_ARCH(avr32:uc)
ENTRY(_start)
/* Do we need any of these for elf?
__DYNAMIC = 0;    */
```

I expect to find calls to _init_startup in this file howver it was not the case.

To summarize here is my questions:

1- where can i find the calls to `_init_startup`

2- why in the linker script i have `ENTRY(_start)` instead of `ENTRY(main)`

3- Where can i find the definition of `_start`

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: When the chip is powered on or reset, it jumps to (starts executing code at) a specific address in memory. The linker arranges for the startup code to be mapped to that address.

Comment: `_start` (or `start`) will most likely be a label in an assembly file, where you'll also find the call to the C function you found.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the feedback; yes but i want know what code is executed before the main, and in case of "code executed before the main" where it is called in the linker script or where exactly ?

Comment: @DanielJour yes it seems something like that, but wich make me crazy is that i didn't find this .s, [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/initstartup), its said that crt0.s calls this function however in my toolchain i only have crt.o, object files, means that i can't have an idea about what happened. this is not fair in my opinion.

Comment: just disassemble the binary, if it uses elf or other formats like that you can see the label names, etc.  and if that is not good enough (even though it would show you your answer) you can then start grepping for the labels and see if you find the source to the bootstrap.

Comment: It can be `crt.o` [on older/simpler systems], `crt0.o`, `crt1.o`, `gcrt1.o`, etc. You just have to look around a bit. Also, `crt.o` is often quite simple. So, you could disassemble it with `objdump`. Also, the `crt.s` source is part of the compiler source, so if you know your compiler (e.g. `gcc`), you can pull that independently and find the `crt*.s` that matches your arch. So, by comparing the disassembly and the `crt.s` files, you should be able to find a pretty good match and/or substitute.

Comment: `_start`  prepare the arguments for `__libc_start_main`  which set the initialization and the cleanup function of the program and then call the `main` function and that's the reason why you find the entry point of `__start` and not  `main`. You can check this [link](http://bottomupcs.sourceforge.net/csbu/x3564.htm)

Comment: When I ask google about it I get https://github.com/avrxml/asf/blob/master/thirdparty/lodepng/example/crt0.S Is that it? Seems to be from  NewLib: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob_plain;f=libgloss/arm/crt0.S

Comment: Questions like these suggest it is past time to learn about tools such as  `grep` and `objdump`

Comment: Every system has some manner of start-up routine, usually called directly through the reset interrupt vector, which sets up the very fundamentals and the ABI: stack pointer, watchdog & LVD, memory mapping, initialize .bss and .data sections etc. When done, it calls `main`. On modern embedded compilers you usually get this code for free with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt worked with Atmel mcu but i assume it same as the other .

1- where can i find the calls to _init_startup?

- You can't,its absolute address jump. you can find it at MCU flash memory reset vector.

2- why in the linker script i have ENTRY(_start) instead of ENTRY(main)?

- Because the first instruction of the code located at address _start.
  after the first piece of code run,it should have jump command pointing to main.

3- Where can i find the definition of _start?

- its probably reserved word.try look for it at compiler options.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however all that i need, _start and init_startup is in the [crt0.s](https://github.com/avrxml/asf/blob/master/thirdparty/lodepng/example/crt0.S). as @ deamentiaemundi pointed